# How can I prevent Visual Studio from building my entire solution when one of the dependent libraries fails to compile?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with several projects in it. There's a Core project and Engine project, which compile to static libs, and a final Game project which links those libraries.

If the Engine has a compile error in it, then that project fails to build. However, Game will still attempt to build and link, presumably using the existing / old Engine library file.

So, even though my build has a compile error, it still produces a final EXE. Is there any way I can stop this?

**EDIT**: Here are the options I am using to reference the first two projects from the final one. Perhaps I am doing something wrong here?

[image: Reference Options]

[image: Linker Options]

Comment: You may want to vote on this feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/355793/add-option-to-stop-projects-building-if-their-depe.html and this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be [StopOnFirstBuildError extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EinarEgilsson.StopOnFirstBuildError) for that purpose. Found reference to it in the [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/355793/add-option-to-stop-projects-building-if-their-depe.html)

Answer (score 1):

Set proper dependencies in your projects: usually all you need is to add references, this way if one of dependent project fails final exe won't build as it wouldn't have all required references.

In your case it seems like you copy some libraries to some other location and then use these copied libs for linking. This would definitely lead to problems like the one you describe if your final exe doesn't use references but has manually configured input libraries in linker settings.

For example, if you use VS 2013 (or any recent version), and have a few static libraries and some executable that depends on them you should do this:

- remove explicit libs from "Additional Dependencies" from linker settings of your executables and dlls.
- remove explicit dependencies from project settings if you set anything manually (for simple cases you don't need to set these).
- add your lib projects to references of your executable or dlls that use these (this properly sets all dependencies, linker inputs etc if you use default VS project settings): 
  [image]

If your Core and Engine are static libraries, then do not make Engine dependent on Core even if Engine uses Core, this way VS can build them in parallel. If Engine is a dll then add Core to References of your Engine project and add references to Engine to your Game project. If Core and Engine are static libs, then simply add references to Core and Engine to your Game project, nothing else is needed.

Try this [sample TestGame VS project](https://filebin.ca/3RUcVRlZZwNg/TestGame.zip).

1. First build TestGame project, try to run it.
2. Go to engine.cpp and introduce some error in that file.
3. Now build TestGame project again. VS first tries to compile TestGameEngine project and this fails and ends entire build process without even attempting to build TestGame project.

At this point TestGame project still has and old binary that was left from previous successful build and if you try to run TestGame it will ask if you want to build it (as it's outdated):
[image]

If you click "No", it will run old binary. If you click "Yes" it will try to build TestGame project again (which will fail again). If you check that box "Do not show this dialog again" and click "No" Visual Studio won't try to rebuild an existing binary even if it's out of date, and will run existing binary and won't ask again about that.

If you click "Yes" after it fails to build updated binary of TestGame it will ask if you want to run old build:
[image]

If in this dialog you also check that box to not ask again you'll probably get that behavior that you describe where VS tries to use last successful build. All you need to do to "uncheck" check check boxes now. You can do that in options (Tools -> Options -> "Project and Solutions" -> "Build and Run"), see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how to set "proper dependencies" in my project?

Right now they are all set up to reference each other in the proper order under "Project Dependencies". The first two projects are set up as "Static Library" as their configuration type. The final project has the other project Library files listed in its "Additional Dependencies" section. I don't do any copying that I know of.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. I removed the library files from the "Additional Dependencies" section, and I made certain that I had references to the first 2 projects. I restarted everything, cleaned and rebuilt. I still have the issue where if the EGEngine library was previously built but fails due to an error, the executable will still be linked using the old lib file. I updated my question with my reference options - perhaps I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: @Raptormeat it's still not clear if your engine/core projects are a static lib or a dll. Also, when you add references you don't need to add lib directories afaik.

Comment: they are static libs! And yeah, I took out the library directories after your original instruction (thanks!). The only library directories left are libs that are external to my build.

Comment: I do not see that behavior with [this sample TestGame project](https://filebin.ca/3RUcVRlZZwNg/TestGame.zip). First build TestGame project, try to run it.

Comment: After that go to engine.cpp and introduce some error in that file. Now build TestGame project again. In my case I tries to compile TestGameEngine project first and this fails and ends entire build without even attempting to build TestGame project. TestGame still have a binary that was left from previous successful build and if you try to run TestGame it will ask if you want to build it (as it's outdated), once it fails, it will offer you to run old build.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this test build. I've discovered that our repro steps are different: If I build the game by hitting the "build solution" button instead of the "Run" button, and I also delete the EXE file, then TestGame will still build and link even if TestGameEngine has a compile error! It seems that perhaps my best option will be to simply clean and rebuild every time I do a build for release.

Comment: @Raptormeat Can you explain in details? Are you saying that with that test solution you also get that same error?

Comment: Yes, I can get the same error with the test build. What I do is 1) Build the solution 2) Add an error to the engine.cpp file 3) Delete the TestGame.exe file 4) Build using the "build solution" button. When I do that, the Engine project will fail to build but the TestGame project will build and link and produce a new EXE.

Comment: @Raptormeat you are totally right, the TestGame project builds and links and produces a new EXE. Which is a bug imo. In my case I have set "Do not launch" in "Build and Run settings" when build or deployment errors occur. So, when I try to run fianl executable from VS it fails build step and doesn't try to run even though it actually builds it.